# How to Join Array of string into single string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, algorithm

Scenario:
I have list of Networks Name in Database Table with numbers e.g (`1. Facebook, 2. Twitter, 3. MySpace, 4. hi5 ...`) and I select one Network from database (e.g  `2. Twitter`).

What I Did:

```
string Selected = "12.FaceBook";
int k=3;
string[] myArray = new string[Selected.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < Selected.Length; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = Selected[k].ToString();
    k++;
}
```

and sucked how to join `myArray` and print in

```
DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("?");
```

What I Want:

output as:

`"Facebook"` or `"Twitter"` without numbers.

Comment: What are you actually after? Your question title asks how to join, but your message is splitting a string into individual characters, and your example seems to want to split on '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string like `"12. Facebook"` then you can easily get the part after the `.` using the [IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx) and the [Substring Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) as follows:

```
string input = "12. Facebook";

string result = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('.') + 1)
                     .Trim();
// result == "Facebook"
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
string joined = string.Join("", myArray);
DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(joined);
```

If you want to put a separator between the joined strings, that's the first parameter of `string.Join()`. For example, to put a space between them:

```
string joined = string.Join(" ", myArray);
```

However, your code to actually create the string array in the first place looks wrong. Do you get a single string back from the database for the required network, or do you get a single string containing all networks that you have to parse yourself?

Comment: _"What I want is ouput as "Facebook" or "Twitter" but with out numbers"_ However, the question is not clear at all.

Comment: thanks Guys almost all answer are correct but I liked this one most.

Comment: "your code to actually create the string array in the first place looks wrong" +1

Comment: @SaeedKhan Your question is a bit ambiguous though, so I wasn't sure if I was really answering it...

Comment: Sorry this gives me "" string

Comment: @SaeedKhan If it does then `myArray` is empty - that's because it wasn't worked out correctly; but all is well - dtb sussed it out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need static string.Join?

or

```
var input="12. Twiiter";
var re=new Regex(@"(?<num>\d+)\.\s*(?<code>.+)");
var m=re.Match(input);
if (m.Success) Console.Write(m.Groups["code"].Value);
```

sorry,

```
var input=new []{"12. ...","9. ..."}
var output = input.Select(x=>string.Join(x.Split(".").Skip(1),".").Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and I Succeeded here is Answer for that, only little adding e.g  Selected.Length-3
and printing output.

Here is My Code

```
try
                {
                    int i;
                    string output = "";

                    string Selected = "12.FaceBook";
                    int k = 3;
                    string[] myArray = new string[Selected.Length];
                    for (i = 0; i < Selected.Length-3; i++)
                    {
                        myArray[i] = Selected[k].ToString();

                        output = output + myArray[i];
                        k++;
                    }


                    DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(output);
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {

                }
```

Comment: This assumes that the input string always starts with a 2-digit number (like `12.`) but not with more or less digits (`1.` or `1000.`) Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply

```
var companiesWithNumber = new[] { "1. Facebook", "2. Twitter", "3. MySpace" };
var companiesWithoutNumber = companiesWithNumber.Select(c => c.Split().Last());
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/pELtc8)

If you need an array:

```
string[] result = companiesWithoutNumber.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `string.Join` method to join the strings,`"string".Split` to split out the number and `string.Format` to add `"` apostrophes.

```
var list = new[] {"1. Facebook", "2. Twitter", "3. MySpace"};

var result = string.Join(" or ",list.Select(s => string.Format("\"{0}\"", s.Split('.')[1].Trim())).ToArray());
DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(result);
```

You can try it [here](http://ideone.com/GiWPFX).

Answer (score -1):

Use regex

```
string s1 = Regex.Replace(Selected, "[^A-Za-z]", "");
```